# multiple updates on different where

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL statement in Python that inserts new data if the row doesn't exist (PRIMARY KEY doesn't exists) or updates columns if they're currently NULL or empty. I'd like to do this in one statement, but keep getting an Error that states SQL Syntax Error, check the manual. Is it possible to do this is a single statement? Or do I need to execute an update for each column?

```
sql_statement = (
    'INSERT INTO database.table '
    '(column_1, column_2, column_3) '
    'VALUES (%s, %s, %s) '
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '
    'SET column_2 = VALUES(column_2) WHERE column_2 IS NULL OR LENGTH(column_2)=0 '
    'SET column_3 = VALUES(column_3) WHERE column_3 IS NULL OR LENGTH(column_3)=0'
)

c.execute(sql_statement)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` fires **only** when some unique (including primary) key violation detected by the insertion. Without unique index it will be executed never. So `column_1` **must** be defined as unique.

Comment: A WHERE clause in an INSERT statement, that does not make sense.

Comment: So if the row _does_ already exist, you’d want to update only the columns that are NULL / empty, but leave all others alone, is that correct? Then you should perhaps go with something that _checks_ the current column content, and sets it to the same value again, if it is not null/empty, and sets the new value otherwise - so an `IF` instead of a WHERE clause, in those SET expressions.